# Setting password on Excel files using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to set password on all excel files in a particular directory. I tried following code but unfortunately it doesn't set password. I can see it opening and closing files but it still doesn't ask for a password when I open files manually.

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim StrFolder As String
    Dim StrFile As String
    StrFolder = "S:\lnb\SecPFM\REPORTS\CRC\201608\"
    StrFile = Dir(StrFolder & "*xls*")
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0

        Workbooks.Open Filename:=StrFolder & StrFile, Password:="OpenFile"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=True
        StrFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong here ? This is with Excel 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe you can set a file password without saving.

So in this instance you will need to `SaveAs`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim StrFolder As String
    Dim StrFile As String
    Dim wb As Workbook

    StrFolder = "S:\lnb\SecPFM\REPORTS\CRC\201608\"
    StrFile = Dir(StrFolder & "*xls*")

    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0

        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=StrFolder & StrFile)

        With wb
            .SaveAs .Path & "\protected_" & .Name, xlExcel12, "OpenFile"
        End With

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=True
        StrFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

You can even just override the existing file if you don't want to create a new protected version:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0

        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=StrFolder & StrFile)

        With wb
            .SaveAs .FullName, , "OpenFile"
        End With

        ActiveWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=True
        StrFile = Dir
    Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```